# how to check that custom (or standard) field represents Id

Tags: sobject, describes

Let's say i want to get Set upon some particular field from recordset

```
public Set<Id> getIdSet(List<SObject> source, String idFieldName) {
    Set<Id> result = new Set<Id>();

    for(SObject item : source) {
        result.add((Id)item.get(idFieldName));
    }
    return result;
}
```

How can I be sure that field we transferred has Id format without using try/catch?

Comment: If you want to use 3 backticks `\`` to format a code block, you need to put the first line of code on a separate line. You also generally need to use another 3 backticks to indicate the end of the code block (again, on their own line). Using 3 backticks means you __don't need to__ put 4 whitespace chars at the start of each line (which is the alternative way to format text as a code block, and what clicking the `{}` button in the post editor does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `instanceOf` to determine if a value is an Id or not:

```
Set<Id> result = new Set<Id>();
for(SObject item : source) {
    Object fieldValue = item.get(idFieldName);
    if(fieldValue instanceOf Id) {
      result.add((Id)fieldValue);
    }
}
return result;
```

This works even if it is a String that is a (potentially valid) Id (e.g. it's 15/18 characters long and matches the style of an ID, with proper keyfix and parity bits).